# correct non www users to full www domain name in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what is the best way to redirect site users who do not enter the www in a domain name to actually get the www site.

IE: I goto Google.com and I am redirected to www.Google.com

Answer (score 2):

The most common way of dealing with this is to do a redirect when the URL isn't what you expected.  Typically this is done using some sort of mod_rewrite module.

In ASP.NET MVC, you would have to catch the incoming request as early as you can in the request lifecycle, check the URL and then redirect (response code 301 or 302) to the correct URL if need be.

I found sample code from this blog post: [Canonical urls With ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rrreese.com/Article/Show/Canonical%20URLS%20With%20ASP.NET%20MVC).  It demonstrates one way of accomplishing this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.Authority.StartsWith("www"))
        return;

    string url = (Request.Url.Scheme
       + "://www."
       + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
       + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
    );

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", url);
    Response.End();
}
```

For those of us doing things with Mono and Apache or using one of the mod_rewrite extensions to IIS, here is a mod_rewrite example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Following these suggestions about having an A record or CNAME only allow people to access the site from both domains, but it reduces your *Google Juice* because you have the same content at two *different* URLs.

Comment: But if you log your site with Google Webmaster tools you can tell it which is the preferred domain and link them there.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Microsoft IIS URL Rewrite Module then the following entry in your web.config will keep your domain consistent.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Consistent Domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mediapopinc.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mediapopinc.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: I am using both the IIS URL Rewrite module and also .Net routing functionality within the webApp iself. Which place would be better to do the redirection from? Or (third option) should I just respond to both and maintain URL for both using a reverse proxy in the URL Rewrite module? ...although that last 3rd option is not ideal for SEO I would think.

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be handed correctly it should be done as an alias on the http server, not in your code...imo.

So when the server is contacted without the www, it should just redirect it to the correct URL.

Comment: or as Andrew mentioned, using a CNAME

Comment: A CNAME is only an alias, it does not do the redirection to the 'other' URL.  Typing in http://example.com/ wouldn't redirect to http://www.example.com/ when using the CNAME or A settings.

Comment: For example, in apache, you can set up a serverAlias that redirects the incoming request.  The CNAME tells what server IP to use, the serverAlias directs the traffic correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Should not ignore the 301 redirections.
There is a nice post written by shahed khan to deal with that kind of situation.
http://dotnetusergroup.com/blogs/shahedkhan/archive/2009/05/18/10229.aspx

Answer (score -3):

This is best handled via an A record (or CNAME record) on the DNS server that manages your domain.  You can handle this in code but it really isn't the proper place for it.

Comment: A and CNAME records can't redirect to another domain. They can only say what is the IP address of a domain. CNAME only tells use the same IP address as another domain.

Comment: Having an A record or CNAME only allow people to access the site from both domains, but it reduces your SEO Page Rank because you have the same content at two different URLs.  The best way to deal with this is to redirect example.com requests to www.example.com URLs in order to keep this consistent.  See my answer to this question for one way to do this in code.